# Importing multiple packages macro in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Most of my jupyter notebooks usually begin with a long list of common packages to import.  E.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

Is there any way I can call all of the same packages using a function defined in another python file?

For example, I tried putting the following in `util.py`:

```
def import_usual_packages():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And in the main notebook:

```
import util
util.import_usual_packages()
```

so that the end effect is I can still call the usual packages without using additional namespaces, e.g.

```
pd.DataFrame()
```

At the moment this wouldn't work with what I have above.  E.g. `pd` isn't defined.

EDIT: It's similar but not exactly the same as other questions asking about how to do a `from util import *`.  I'm trying to put the import statements inside functions of the utility python file, not simply at the top of the file. I'm aware that I can simply put e.g. `import pandas as pd` at the top of the util file and then run from `util import *`, but that is not what I'm looking for. Putting it within functions gives me additional control. For example, I can have 2 different functions called `import_usual_packages()` and `import_plotting_packages()` within the same util file that calls different groups of packages, so that in my notebook I can simply call

```
import_usual_packages()
import_plotting_packages()
```

instead of having 10+ lines calling the same stuff everytime.  This is purely for personal use so I don't care about if other people don't understand what's going on (in fact, that might be a good thing in some circumstances).

Comment: You could put them all in a separate file, and then import that file. But I am not sure there is much point in doing that, as now whoeever reads it cannot see what's in scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Importing an "import file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206204/python-importing-an-import-file)

Comment: It's similar but not exactly the same as the other thread.  I'm trying to put the import statements inside functions of the utility python file.  I'm aware that I can simply put e.g. ``import pandas as pd`` at the top of the util file and then run ``from util import *``, but putting it within functions gives me additional control.  For example, I can have 2 different functions called ``import_usual_packages()`` and ``import_plotting_packages()`` within the same util file.

Answer (score 0):

With some slight modifications your method can work. In `util.py`

```
def import_usual_packages():
    global pd, np    # Make the names pd & np global
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
```

And in `main.py`

```
import utils

utils.import_usual_packages()

utils.pd.DataFrame()  # access via the utils namespace
```

This is definitely not the cleanest approach though.

Comment: How can I change it so that I don't need to have the ``utils.`` namespace?  I.e., so that in your last line I just need to call ``pd.DataFrame()``?

Comment: `from utils import pd` after the call to `import_usual_packages`