# How to import multiple different import using importlib on python?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a python file that is beginning to have a lot of import statements like

```
from enum import auto
```

Let's say I have a file called a.py and a.py uses `from enum import auto`.
Is there a way that I can create a separate file called `imports.py` that imports all the modules that I specify using importlib?

I have tried the following with no success:

```
modules.append(importlib.import_module(auto, Package=enum))
```

(modules is an array that will hold the imported modules)

The error says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File ".import.py", line 17, in <module>
      modules.append(importlib.import_module(auto,Package=enum))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206204/python-importing-an-import-file

is this what you're referring to?

Comment: @raja777m, I was specifically trying to use importlib but that seems to work as well.